# C# / .NET: Move to desired Item in BindingNavigator

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

I'm using [such](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zhc8d2f(VS.80).aspx) a BindingNavigator to let the User move through Data Records of a BindingSource. **How can I change the displayed page to a desired page number through the program?**

I already set the PositionItem to the desired page number, but that just changes the displayed page number and doesnt move to this page.

*I'm sure it's not difficult, but I'm searching the solution for quite a hour now. So I'm asking u guys now...*

Comment: What is a 'page' here? A record?

Comment: A record in the BindingNavigator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In code, you do **not**  navigate using the BindingNavigator.

Use the Find, MoveXxx and Position members of the BindingSource.

Comment: Thank you. Thats the solution: bindingNavigator.BindingSource.Position = desiredPositionAsInt;